# How to only get the ID from EF Linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am attempting to get a list of Order Ids from a EF linq query.  The sql query is returning back quickly but I think the EF framework is trying to create the full entity.  I only want the ID of the order. It seems that it creates the whole entity and then it parses it out to only the id.  Which seems to be a complete waste of resources.

Orders are a complex object that includes lots of child entitys.  I dont need anything but the Ids of the orders in the list.  Orders are organized into OrderCollection which is a many to many relationship.

The basic query in English is get the order ids in the specified order collection and have a cart date newer then the date specified and only send the specified page (skip and take).

example:

```
_repo.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderCollection.Any(r => r.Id == RoutingRuleId)).ToList()
                    .Where(o => o.OrderDate >= StartDateTime)
                            .OrderBy(x => x.OrderDate )
                            .Skip(RecordsToSkipCount)
                            .Take(BatchSize).Select(x => new { x.Id }).ToArray();
```

The sql runs in just 102ms for this in debug mode.  But afterwards I see the memory go to up 4GB before failing. The batchsize is only 100.  Its like it grabbing everything.

I tried moving the select around but that failed also or gave syntax errors or poor performance in running the sql (SQL taking 16 seconds).

Example

```
    _repo.Orders.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.OrderCollection, x.OrderDate})
                   .Where(o => o.OrderCollection.Any(r => r.Id == RoutingRuleId)).ToList()
                    .Where(o => o.OrderDate >= StartDateTime)
                            .OrderBy(x => x.OrderDate )
                            .Skip(RecordsToSkipCount)
                            .Take(BatchSize).Select(x => new { x.Id }).ToArray();
```

The database has millions of records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is roughly;

```cs
List<Order> list = _repo.Orders
    .Where(o => o.OrderCollection.Any(r => r.Id == RoutingRuleId))
    .ToList();

list.Where(o => o.OrderDate >= StartDateTime)
    .OrderBy(x => x.OrderDate )
    .Skip(RecordsToSkipCount)
    .Take(BatchSize)
    .Select(x => new { x.Id })
    .ToArray();
```

That first `.ToList` is forcing EF Core to load every order with a matching routing rule into memory. The rest of the expression is then using `IEnumerable` extension methods to process those results.

I think you want to rearrange that to;

```cs
IQueryable<Order> query = _repo.Orders
    .Where(o => o.OrderCollection.Any(r => r.Id == RoutingRuleId)
        && o.OrderDate >= StartDateTime)
    .OrderBy(x => x.OrderDate )
    .Skip(RecordsToSkipCount)
    .Take(BatchSize)
    .Select(x => new { x.Id });

query.ToArray();
```

Creating an `IQueryable` doesn't trigger EF Core to execute any SQL. An `IQueryable` is just a description of the query you would like to run. Then it's the `.ToArray` method that will finally cause EF Core to compile and execute an sql statement.